# Excel VBA inserting date into cell produces incorrect format

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping someone can help with a funny issue I'm having. Using the following Excel VBA code to update a cell with a date in a sheet. The cell is formatted to "DD/MM"YYYY" my local PC is set to this also.

```
Dim SelectedDate As String
SelectedDate = "05/02/2018"
Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Value = Format(SelectedDate,"dd/mm/yyyy")

MsgBox Format(SelectedDate,"dd/mm/yyyy") ' Returns 05/02/2018 - Correct

MsgBox Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Value ' Returns 02/05/2018 - Incorrect
```

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to get confused with Excel, VBA and date formats.  Even easier when you are using strings instead of dates in VBA and/or on the worksheet.  And it will be easier to figure out what is going on if you format your output to unambiguous dates eg: dd-mmm-yyyy.

- You are entering a string into F36.  VBA is US Centric and thinks the string represents `May 2, 2018`
- To have the string interpreted the same as your windows short date format, you can use the Datevalue function and treat your entries as **dates** and not as strings.

So one alternative to your code would be:

```
Sub marine()
Dim SelectedDate As Date
SelectedDate = DateValue("05/02/2018") 'will convert to 5-Feb-2018
Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Value = SelectedDate

MsgBox Format(SelectedDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") 

MsgBox format(Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Value,"dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NumberFormat` properties just define the way the underlying value is visually represented, but it doesn't change the underlying value itself. Instead of printing the `Value` property, use `Text` (which holds the formatted representation of the underlying value):

```
MsgBox Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Text
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick on the `Value` property of the cell, you are forced to print it as follows:

```
MsgBox Format(Sheets("CONTROL").Range("F36").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, However it is storing the date in the cell as 02/05/2018 instead of 05/02/2018 too completely different dates. therefore it is not the visual format that is the issue, it is excel converting the date and interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: Interestingly if I change SelectedDate = "02/05/2018" (mm,dd,yyyy) then it produces the correct result of dd,mm,yyyy when its stored. Which will mean I will just have to account for this in the users input.

Comment: You have to set the cell value before defining it's format. Try this.